# how to download file with service in the background?

Tags: android

I'm making a android library app that can download and show special files. now I need to write a service that download file in background! are there samples for services?

and I want to save files in SD, because users can update app and don't should miss downloaded files.

If you have a suggest or opinion for this, write me, please.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("url from apk file is to be downloaded");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard, "filename.ext");

    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferLength = 0;

    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    }
    fileOutput.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

**Permission:** To write to external storage, you need to add this permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

**Note:** you can use above code to get the file downloaded and saved in the SD card. You can run this code in background using [AsysnTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) or `thread`.

Comment: here is very good tutorial:http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidPerformance/article.html

Comment: Be careful: `setDoOutput(true)` was ruining the download process for me, returning 400 Bad request for all the URL connections.
Once removed, everything was fixed

Answer (score 8):

This is another sample:

```
try {
        //set the download URL, a url that points to a file on the internet
        //this is the file to be downloaded
        URL url = new URL("http://somewhere.com/some/webhosted/file");

        //create the new connection
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        //set up some things on the connection
        urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);

        //and connect!
        urlConnection.connect();

        //set the path where we want to save the file
        //in this case, going to save it on the root directory of the
        //sd card.
        File SDCardRoot = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
        //create a new file, specifying the path, and the filename
        //which we want to save the file as.
        File file = new File(SDCardRoot,"somefile.ext");

        //this will be used to write the downloaded data into the file we created
        FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);

        //this will be used in reading the data from the internet
        InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        //this is the total size of the file
        int totalSize = urlConnection.getContentLength();
        //variable to store total downloaded bytes
        int downloadedSize = 0;

        //create a buffer...
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int bufferLength = 0; //used to store a temporary size of the buffer

        //now, read through the input buffer and write the contents to the file
        while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
                //add the data in the buffer to the file in the file output stream (the file on the sd card
                fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
                //add up the size so we know how much is downloaded
                downloadedSize += bufferLength;
                //this is where you would do something to report the prgress, like this maybe
                updateProgress(downloadedSize, totalSize);

        }
        //close the output stream when done
        fileOutput.close();

//catch some possible errors...
} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: thanks, too
your code is like sample of Vineet Shukla. but comments in the code useful for me.

Comment: How to achieve this download file in background?

Comment: you can do it in a class that extends AsyncTask.