# How to download files on Android tablets using any app/script

Tags: android

I have created scenario of multiples files downloading when my website is
accessed "http://afzaal.net/test/test.html". when you access this link multiple files will be downloaded in chrome browser one time.

MY Question is there any free andriod app which I can use to download all files from this server on hourly basis like "goodSynch" or any script which I can run on android device on hourly basis (like we do in cron job on Linux os)

Thank you

Comment: Did you consider making an android application to do this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8276913/how-to-download-file-with-service-in-the-background

Comment: Yes But I am using webView in my app and it do not allow to download files