# download and store image from url

Tags: android, file, url, android-bitmap

I want to download an image from the given url. the downloaded image should save in SD card. I have used the below code.

```
     URL newurl = null;
                    try {
                        newurl = new URL(strHitRes);
                    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                    try {
                        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) newurl.openConnection();
                        connection.setDoInput(true);
                        connection.connect();
                        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
                        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
                        String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
                        File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");
                        myDir.mkdirs();
                        Random generator = new Random();
                        int n = 10000;
                        n = generator.nextInt(n);
                        String fname = "Image-"+ n +".jpg";
                        File file = new File (myDir, fname);
                        if (file.exists ()) file.delete ();
                        try {
                            FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
                            myBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"download successful",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            out.flush();
                            out.close();

                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

But image is not downloading. Even i tested in debug mode, i found that my bitmap is null. How to solve this.

Comment: Did you add necessary permissions in Manifest file?

Comment: It works normally in my device. So firstly let check if you add INTERNET and WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE or not. Secondly, check your if url link to valid image.

Comment: i have added all required permissions

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: my url link is valid and it will open in browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***//To download bitmap from URL***

```
public Bitmap getbmpfromURL(String surl){
        try {
            URL url = new URL(surl);
            HttpURLConnection urlcon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlcon.setDoInput(true);
            urlcon.connect();
            InputStream in = urlcon.getInputStream();
            Bitmap mIcon = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in);
            return  mIcon;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**To save bitmap to SD card**

```
private void SaveImage(Bitmap finalBitmap) {

   String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
   File myDir = new File(root + "/saved_images");    
   myDir.mkdirs();
   Random generator = new Random();

   String fname = "Image.jpg";
   File file = new File (myDir, fname);
   if (file.exists ()) file.delete (); 
   try {
       FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
       finalBitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 90, out);
       out.flush();
       out.close();

   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
}
```

**And don't forget to use below permission in your manifest.xml**

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: Sorry but this is NOT the way to download files to device storage. Why is it marked as correct answer? Take the other one.

Comment: #greenapps if you have any alternatives, you can post . its working for me.

Comment: `Take the other one.` i said. I already told you the alternative. The better one. You could have read it. The other answer is the best one as it does not use Bitmap nor BitmapFactory. The answer of @Prakash U.

Answer (score 1):

Say thanks to Vineet for his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8276941/6711591)

```
try {
    URL url = new URL("url from apk file is to be downloaded");
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
    urlConnection.setRequestMethod("GET");
    urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);
    urlConnection.connect();

    File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File file = new File(sdcard, "filename.ext");

    FileOutputStream fileOutput = new FileOutputStream(file);
    InputStream inputStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    int bufferLength = 0;

    while ( (bufferLength = inputStream.read(buffer)) > 0 ) {
        fileOutput.write(buffer, 0, bufferLength);
    }
    fileOutput.close();

} catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: Yes this is the way to do it. Dont use Bitmap and BitmapFactory to download images. The image will have had a high resolution. So high that a bitmap could not be made and BitmapFactory returned null.

Comment: `urlConnection.setDoOutput(true);`. There is no output done.

Comment: thanks dude for the reply, it is working fine. I want the code to be seperated as Ashis Parajuli posted down.

Comment: Dont understand your comment. What are you trying to tell?